# How do I toggle Caps Lock in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net

Using VB.NET, how do I toggle the state of Caps Lock?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?referrerid=61394&t=537891

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form2

    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" ( _
        ByVal bVk As Byte, _
        ByVal bScan As Byte, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Integer, _
        ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer _
    )
    Private Const VK_CAPITAL As Integer = &H14
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY As Integer = &H1
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2

    Private Sub Button1_Click( _
        ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs _
    ) Handles Button1.Click

        ' Toggle CapsLock

        ' Simulate the Key Press
        keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)

        ' Simulate the Key Release
        keybd_event(VK_CAPITAL, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 7):

Try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/718c0860-ab1a-4a0a-98af-a101cdfecf4e/):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock, &H14, 1, 0)
            Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock, &H14, 3, 0)
        End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wow! 3 lines of code instead of a page... I wish I could vote +5.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Integer)
Private Const KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY As Integer = &H1
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP As Integer = &H2
'put this where you want to turn caps lock on or off
keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or 0, 0)
keybd_event(VK_NUMLOCK, &H45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY Or KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```