# Detecting if shift/caps lock is on

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the current state of Caps Lock in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976/how-do-i-get-the-current-state-of-caps-lock-in-vb-net)

I am wanting to create two functions related to key input:

```
Dim capsLock As Boolean = GetCapsLockState() 'imaginary function
Dim shiftKey As Boolean = GetShiftKeyState() 'imaginary function
```

Can someone help me with these functions...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using .NET 2.0 or later, you can use the [Control.IsKeyLocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx) method.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Public Class CapsLockIndicator

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
            MessageBox.Show("The Caps Lock key is ON.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("The Caps Lock key is OFF.")
        End If
    End Sub 'Main

End Class 'CapsLockIndicator
```

Comment: It is, indeed. It was introduced back in .NET 2.0.

Comment: This works well: Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)... how do I detect if the shift key is being pressed though? This does not work: Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.LShiftKey)

Comment: All done. Here is the code: (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Shift) = Keys.Shift