# How To Send Lower Caps String On VB.NET Using Sendkeys.send Whihe Shift key pressed

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I want to sendkey "hello" using sendkeys command in vb.net but it sending "HELLO" because shift button is true. 
Now How to send "hello" in lower case when shift key is true...

Comment: Care to show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning caps lock on using keybd_event in user32.dll. With caps lock on, you can "hold down" shift while "typing" lower case letters. Send Keys mimics using the keyboard, so you have to think about how you would do this with an actual keyboard.

See [How do I toggle Caps Lock in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937/how-do-i-toggle-caps-lock-in-vb-net)